# How should I do image processing in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I'm making an applet that lets users crop out a piece of an image and save it.  For cropping, I'm going to implement a "magic wand"-esque tool.  I can do all this in Matlab but i'm having some trouble figuring out the Java libraries.  Here are a few tasks I need to perform:

- Randomly access pixels in an image by (x,y) and return a single object (java.awt.Color, ARGB int, short[], whatever -- as long as I'm not dealing with channels individually)
- Create an alpha channel from a boolean[ ][ ]
- Create a N by M image that's initialized to green

Any pros out there who can help me?  Just some code snippets off the top of your head would be fine.

Many thanks,

Neal

Comment: Have you looked at Java Advanced Imaging API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use the Java2D libraries. Specifically, you want to use the `BufferedImage` class from the library to deal with your images. You can access individual pixels and do all of the things you have specified above. Sun/Oracle has a [good tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) to get you started in the right direction. The second part in that tutorial goes over creating an alpha channel. Oh, and to access individual pixels, you want to use the `WritableRaster` class. So you can do something like this. Hope this gets you started.

```
WritableRaster imageRaster = Bufferedimg.getRaster();
//use java random generation to get a random x and y coordinate, then call this to access the pixel
imageRaster.getPixel(x, y,(int[])null);
```

Comment: BTW, your link to the tutorial is broken, it has an extra `l` at the end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

[`ImageJ`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) is a mature, open-source image processing framework that supports macros,  plugins and a host of other [features](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/features.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net) is a Java image processing framework that can help you. It provides algorithms for filtering, feature extraction, morphological analysis, tranformations, segmentation and so forth. Moreover, its architecture supports real-time video processing with the same algorithms.